# Is there any way to fill form in without form tag in html using firefox in autoit?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, autoit

I am trying to fill a web form with my script it will fill web forms which is having `<form> </form>`. But my site does not have this in HTML. Is there any way to fill this in firefox using AutoIt?

However, `_FF_AutoLogin($uName,$pwd,$url)` will fail in such case. So I am using

```
_FFSetValue($uName,$formUID,"id")
   _FFSetValue($pwd,$formPID,"id")
```

even this is not filling requirement. Can any one suggest me where i am going wrong. I am using latest version of mozilla along with mozrepl-addon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[_FFSetValueById](http://english.documentation.ff-au3.thorsten-willert.de/ff_functions/_FFSetValueById.php)** to set the value of the element based on its ID.

Comment: but there is no function called "_FFSetValueById".I read this in one forum.After that  i used_FFSetValue

Comment: _FFSetValueById: showing an error ...."D:\My_Files\Automation scripts\FF-mozilla\Gmail1.au3" (42) : ==> Unknown function name.:
_FFSetValueById($uName,$formUID)
^ ERROR
>Exit code: 1    Time: 2.513

Comment: _FFSetValueById is not present in FF.au3,FF_autoLogin.au3 then is it there in any other directory